# Proper use of mixins in python

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

Let's suppose that A, B, and C are classes.  C inherits from A and B thereby utilizing them as mixins.

At this point, A can access any attributes on B and C through self.whatever.  B can access any attributes on A and C through self.whatever.  And C can access any attributes on A and B through self.whatever.

Are there any good articles, or is there a consensus, on which of these should "know" about how to interact with the others when using this "mixing" pattern in python?  For instance should C only utilize functionality in A/B but not vice-versa?  Or should A/B only utilize functionality on C but not vice-versa?

EDIT - This is code I inherited from another author.  The explanation was that when using the mixin pattern in python, this is acceptable design.  You guys confirmed that it's not.  As I mentioned below in a comment I would never go about object-oriented design in this way and I'll be refactoring the code.  I was open to the possibility that there was something about the "mixin" pattern I didn't understand, hence the question.  Also thanks for the down votes.

Comment: You appear to be seriously confused as to how classes in Python work. Your examples of access between classes do not really make sense.

Comment: "Mixins" do not exist in Python (as a syntactic structure; the pattern could be implemented in code). It's straight inheritance.

Comment: @Marcin, what I mentioned above *does* work, technically.  This is not code that I wrote and I'm trying to give some benefit of the doubt to the author because there's a mixin pattern used in Python which I don't seem to understand.  In other object-oriented technologies that I've used some parts of what I listed above aren't even technically possible and even if they were, it'd be horrendous object-oriented design.  I'll be refactoring the code to straighten it out.

Answer (score 0):

Can A be instantiated by itself? If it can, it must not depend on C. Ditto for B on C. As a generalisation, an instantiable class should only depend on itself and its superclasses, never subclasses.

There are possible exceptions to this, where a superclass may need to know about its subclasses, but this is probably an indication of poor design, due to the (generally undesirable) coupling.

Comment: What would be even worse is if `B` would depend on functionality from `A`, like suggested in the question. Those two classes have *nothing* in common and it's bare coincidence that they get connect through a common subclass.

Comment: Totally agreed.  In the codebase I'm looking at A, B, and C could really have been defined as one class.  The only reason they were separated was to avoid one humungous file.  A and B are considered mixins that are inherited by C.  In a few bases A and B depend on each other and like you say, this just feels wrong.  Even more wrong than A and B depending on being subclassed and using functionality in their subclass.  This is weird design, I'll refactor it.

Comment: To answer your question, the author of the code never intended A to be instantiated by itself.